# Syntactic sugar JavaScript ( If statement) Error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntactic-sugar

Most times we use If else statements and writing its sytactic sugar equivalent is easy.

```
If(condition){trueExecute}else{falseExecute}
```

syntactic sugar of it is

```
condition?trueExecute:falseExecute
```

But I am experiencing a problem in my code below because i don't want to **use the else**. And on top of that i want to **use the break or continue** functions in a loop. When I use the normal If statement; the code is perfect. But anytime I try to use syntactic sugar to replace the if, it fails to execute.

Is there a possible solution to this because all examples I'm finding, none has  addressed this

My code:

```
const NUMBER = 5346789123;
let anotherNew = NUMBER.toString();
let stringNumber = "";
let newString = anotherNew.length;

for(let numCount = 0; numCount < newString; numCount++){

if (anotherNew[numCount] == 4){

    console.log('we have removed 4');
    continue;
}
if (anotherNew[numCount] == 9){

    console.log('we have a break');
    break;
}
stringNumber += anotherNew[numCount];
console.log(stringNumber);  
}
```

Syntactic Sugar I am trying to use to replace the if statement but it results in an error

```
anotherNew[numCount] == 4? console.log('we have removed 4') continue;

anotherNew[numCount] == 9? console.log('we have a break') break;
```

Comment: The conditional operator is *not* syntax sugar for `if/else`. The conditional operator evaluates to an *expression*, whereas `if/else` executes *statements*. They're suited for different things. Best not to abuse the conditional operator just to save on a few characters, you'll confuse readers of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to use syntactic sugar

[The conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is not *syntactic sugar*.  It's a specific operator with a specific purpose, and you're simply using it incorrectly.  It is used for conditionally *producing a value* as an overall expression, one value if the condition is true and another if it's false.

For example:

```
let x = input == 'one' ? 1 : 0;
```

This expression produces an integer value based on a condition.

What you're trying to do is simply execute a block of code if a condition is true.  And you already have the tool for that, an `if` statement:

```
if (anotherNew[numCount] == 4){
    console.log('we have removed 4');
    continue;
}
```

The overall lesson here is to not try to get *too clever* with your code.  You're using an `if` statement for its exact and correct purpose.  The code is simple, explicit, and easy to understand at even a casual glance.  These are all good things.  Don't replace them with terse and complicated code which uses tools in unintuitive ways just to save a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

```
anotherNew[numCount] == 4? console.log('we have removed 4') continue;

anotherNew[numCount] == 9? console.log('we have a break') break;
```

This is more than syntactic sugar. It is a ternary operator or a conditional statement. It cannot always replace an if else block in the code.

The ternary operator executes statements and on basis or whether they evaluate to `true` or `false` gives the output, while in an if/else block we can give any conditions we want. There is a huge difference. You cannot blindly use one in place of another. There are certain rules you have to keep in mind while using them.